# Mock call in Typescript in unit test using only Mocha

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have the following method:

```
import { ObjectDal } from "./ObjectDal";

export class ObjectBL {
  async getObject(id) {
      try {
          let dal = new ObjectDal();

          let result = await dal.get(id);

          return result;

      } catch (err) {
          // log the error
      }
}
```

where the `ObjectDal` class is:

```
export class ObjectDal {
    async get(id) {
        // open connection to db
        // make a query based on id

        // put the result in a `result` variable

        return result;
    }
}
```

I have to write an unit test for the `getObject()` method using **only** Mocha...

This is the begining of the UT:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectBL = require("../ObjectBL");

describe('Something', () => {
    describe('...', () => {
        it('getObject_GetsObjectUsingID_True', async () => {
            // arange
            let id = "123456789101";
            let expected = {
                "name": "ana",
                "hasApples": true
            };

            let test = new ObjectBL.ObjectBL();

            let result = await test.getObject(id);

            assert.deepStrictEqual(result, expected);
        });
    });
});
```

But in this case I would have to call the method from the `ObjectDal` class...

How can I mock the call to the `get()` method using only Mocha?

I found answers with Sinon, or Mocha with Sinon and/or Chai... but nothing with only Mocha...

Answer (score 0):

Proxies might be the way to go for you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

You could mok methods by using a Proxy like so:

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectBL = require("../ObjectBL");

describe('Something', () => {
    describe('...', () => {
        it('getObject_GetsObjectUsingID_True', async () => {
            // arange
            let id = "123456789101";
            let expected = {
                "name": "ana",
                "hasApples": true
            };

            let test = new ObjectBL.ObjectBL();
            
            const handler = {
              get: function(obj, prop) {
                // mok the getObject method
                if(prop === 'getObject'){
                  return () => {
                    return Promise.resolve({
                        "name": "ana",
                        "hasApples": true
                    });
                   }
                } else {
                  return obj[prop];
                }
              }
            };
            const p = new Proxy(test, handler);

            let result = await p.getObject(id);

            assert.deepStrictEqual(result, expected);
        });
    });
});
```

If you ONLY want to mok the `ObjectDal.get` method, you might want to override the prototype and recover it afterwards:

```js
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectBL = require("../ObjectBL");
const ObjectDal = require("../ObjectDal");

describe('Something', () => {
    describe('...', () => {
        it('getObject_GetsObjectUsingID_True', async () => {
            // arange
            let id = "123456789101";
            let expected = {
                "name": "ana",
                "hasApples": true,
            };
            
            const proto = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ObjectDal, 'prototype').value;
            
            const backup = proto.get;
            proto.get = () => {
              return Promise.resolve({
                  "name": "ana",
                  "hasApples": true,
              });
            }

            let test = new ObjectBL.ObjectBL();

            let result = await test.getObject(id);
            
            ObjectDal.prototype.get = backup;
            
            assert.deepStrictEqual(result, expected);
        });
    });
});
```

You could also override the `ObjectDal` with a Proxy and implement the `construct` handler to return a dummy `ObjectDal`, but this might be more tricky, since you are working with modules.

Comment: when I try to run the second example, I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`... might this be because it's a TS file and I'm targeting ES6?

Comment: This should not be a Problem. But you might need to require `ObjectDal`.

Comment: Ahh. Sorry misread the error. Jea typescript will prevent you from doing this,
since you will override the prototype. You need to do this: `(ObjectDal as any).prototype.get` (VERY UGLY), or use `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` like so: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Test, 'prototype').value.get`

Answer (score 0):

Testing is feedback, not just on whether or not your code works as advertised but even more crucially *on the quality of your design*.

The fact that you are having trouble writing the tests is your first sign you did something sub-optimal in the implementation. What you want is *this*:

```
export class ObjectBL {
  constructor (dal) {
      this.dal = dal;
  }

  async getObject(id) {
      try {
          let result = await this.dal.get(id);

          return result;

      } catch (err) {
          // log the error
      }
}
```

...and now the dependency is *clear* rather than implicit and will show up in editor tooltips, is more amenable to static analysis, etc. And it solves your problem: now you can mock it easily for testing, no further libraries needed.